# Does ${\rm card}({\rm Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p ))$ equal to $(p^2 -1)(p^2-p)$? $(p \in \mathbb{P})$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, automorphism-group

Suppose that we have $G=\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$, where $p\in \mathbb{P}$. I know that every arbitrary permutation of the elements of $G$ such that $ \forall x \in G: {\rm ord}(f(x))=o(x) \Rightarrow f\in {\rm Aut}(G)$. Therefore, we can write $G$ group as follows:$$G=\{x^i,y^j,x^ky^l\mid i,j,k,l\in \{0,...,p-1\}\}=\langle x,y\rangle .$$ where $x=(1,0)$ and $y=(0,1)$. I know that $f(e)=e$ and $(\forall x\in G) \land (\forall f\in{\rm Aut}(G)):{\rm ord}(f(x))={\rm ord}(x)$ But, $\forall x\in G:{\rm ord}(x)\mid|\mathbb{Z}_p|\Rightarrow ({\rm ord}(x)=1) \lor ({\rm ord}(x)=p)$. Therefore,$\forall x \in G: ({\rm ord}(x)=p) \lor (x=e)$.

If I can define the correspondent elements of $f(x)=\bar x$ and $f(y)=\bar y$ ($\bar x,\bar y \in G$). I have $p^2-1$ candidate elements for $\bar x$ and $p^2-p$ candidate elements for $\bar y$ (because $ord(\bar x)=p,\forall \bar x \in G $ and $f(\bar y)\notin \langle\bar x\rangle$. Thus,$|{\rm Aut}(G)|=(p^2-1)(p^2-p)$.

Is it correct? If it's not, can you please indicate my mistakes? Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: Please use `\langle` and `\rangle`, not `<` and `>`.

Comment: Your description of $G$ is too complicated; the elements $x^i$ can be obtained as elements $x^ky^l$ with $l=0$; similarly with $y^j$. Your solution is incomplete; you’ve argued that there are at most that many automorphisms. But you haven’t proven that any such choice will give you an automorphism. It’s much easier if you think of this as a vector space of dimension of $2$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: I believe this answer is correct. It's the same as the number of invertible $2\times2$ matrices over $\Bbb Z_p$, which makes sense when we think of the group $\Bbb Z_p\times\Bbb Z_p$ as a vector space.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, excuse me, I haven't used to LaTeX and I didn't know that thare was a better way to write it. Thank you very much for your suggestion which improved my knowledge.
Thank you also for your second helpful comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on Greg's comment, your answer is indeed correct. An automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p$ can be thought of as an invertible 2×2 matrix with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Thus $|\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p)|=|\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)|$. So how many of these matrices are there? Giving a 2×2 invertible matrix is the same as finding two linearly independent vectors over $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Well, let's take any nonzero vector $v$. There are $p^2-1$ such choices. Now we need to see how many vectors are linearly independent from $v$. But it's actually much easier to see how many linearly *dependent* vectors there are to $v$. Such vectors  must of course be of the form $av$ for some $a\in \mathbb{Z}_p$. So there are $p$ vectors linearly *dependent* to $v$, and hence $p^2-p$ vectors linearly *independent* to $v$. Putting it all together, there are $(p^2-1)(p^2-p)$ pairs of linearly independent vectors.

Comment: Indeed, by thinking of it as a linear transformation, we don’t need to check that any choice will yield an automorphism, since we know that we can pick the images of the basis arbitrarily and induce a transformation. The original post does not do this, however, so there is a need to verify that the choices will indeed yield a homomorphism... or to argue that they induce one as you implicitly do here.